# Could not resolve com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.2

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i am trying to import network library , but android studio shows up with this meessage:ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.2.

here is the build.gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myfaild"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: show your build.gradle  project level

Comment: Move to androidX at first

Answer (score 8):

I know this is the old question, but I saw such a problem after removing jcenter() from repositories in gradle file:

```
repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

this worked for me ,i had to add jitpack.io

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
 compile 'com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.2'
```

**When using it with Jackson Parser**

```
implementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:jackson-android-networking:1.0.2'
```

**When using it with RxJava**

```
implementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:rx-android-networking:1.0.2'
```

**When using it with RxJava2**

```
compile 'com.amitshekhar.android:rx2-android-networking:1.0.2'
```

Comment: `compile` is obsolete . Also it does not make any diffrence .

Comment: i have same problem with them again

Comment: Can you share your gradle-wrapper.properties file ?

Comment: #Mon Jul 27 15:29:49 IRDT 2020
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip

Comment: Replace last line with distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip

Comment: ERROR: Minimum supported Gradle version is 5.1.1. Current version is 4.6.

Answer (score 0):

add this line in gradle.properties:

```
# Automatically convert third-party libraries to use AndroidX
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this was resolved a while ago, but I was working on this now and found a perfect way.

We should add 2 things here:

1. `jcenter()` in `settings.gradle` file under both `pluginManagement` and `dependencyResolutionManagement`
2. add `android.enableJetifier=true` in `gradle.properties` file